# xymatrix upright arrow breaks labeling

Tags: xy-pic

When I try to compile the following diagram

```
\xymatrix
{
A\ar[r]^{g}{\ar[d]_j} & B\ar[d]^{e}\\
X\ar[r]_{f} \ar[ur]^{\tilde g}& Y
}
```

the subscripts of the arrow labels are treated as the subscripts of A and X, but if I take out the diagonal arrow it compiles normally

```
\xymatrix
{
A\ar[r]^{g}{\ar[d]_j} & B\ar[d]^{e}\\
X\ar[r]_{f} & Y
}
```

Is this just me or a bug? How do I fix it?

Edit: here are pics of the compiled diagrams

no diagonal

[image]

diagonal

[image]

Edit 2: I just tried compiling the same thing in my Texclipse setup but it actually comes out the same way. So it's not an Anki problem.

Comment: Are you loading `\usepackage[all]{xy}`? It works here using TeXlive 2014.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please post an image of your output?

Comment: @Sigur yes I'm calling `\usepackage[all]{xy}` in the preamble

Comment: What's Anki that you mention in a comment?

Comment: The [website](http://ankisrs.net/) gives a pretty good intro to it. It's a software that helps increase retention rate for learning. It allows compilation of latex into jpeg (I believe) so that mathematical knowledge can be gained efficiently with this method as well. For most cases, the implemented latex conversion system works, but for diagrams, for example, I can't do tikz-cd.

Comment: Is your problem solved with my answer? If yes, please consider to [accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) it in order to close this post. If not, please tell us, what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide an MWE as your problem is not reproducible for us. Your snippet works just fine as I am showing below. However, I provide a transcript to [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd) which is much more modern and maybe interesting for you.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document} 
\[\xymatrix{%
    A\ar[r]^{g}\ar[d]_j & B\ar[d]^{e}\\
    X\ar[r]_{f} \ar[ur]^{\tilde g} & Y
}\]
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    A\ar{r}{g}\ar{d}[swap]{j} & B\ar{d}{e} \\
    X\ar{r}[swap]{f}\ar{ur}{\tilde{g}} & Y
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what is an MWE? To put this in context, I'm writing this snippet in [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/), which doesn't support tikz for some reason I'm forgetting.

Comment: We often use the abbreviation [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for a compilable but small version of your document. If you can't use Ti*k*Z, you will have to tell me, what is wrong with my `XY` approach-